# Lightweight windows xp for running .net 4 application

Tags: windows, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I need to create an extremly light version of WinXP pro (with nLite) capable to run .net 4 application.
What are the minimum requirments to use .net 4 framework? What can i remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN article .NET Framework System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8z6watww.aspx) aside from I.E. 6.0 (or later) and Windows Install 3.1 you don't need anything else to install the framework.

After that its all based on application specific requirements.  For example if your application needed to write to a local MSMQ you'd need Message Queuing installed and turned on.

Comment: And what are the minimum service needed for a stable windows installation?

Comment: Try the answer at this [superuser question: What Windows services can I safely disable?](http://superuser.com/questions/94/what-windows-services-can-i-safely-disable)